# Transpose Columns to Rows - Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

I have two tables with the following data

```
TABLEA
TYPES   COLUMNA COLUMNB COLUMNC
DART    8.00     9.00   10.00

TABLEB
TYPES  DESCP    ACNT
DART  COLUMNA 14000
DART  COLUMNB 15000
DART  COLUMNC 16000
```

My expected output is

```
TYPES AMT   ACNT
DART 8.00  14000
DART 9.00  15000
DART 10.00 16000
```

I have written the following code to get the output

```
 SELECT X.TYPES,
 CASE WHEN DESCP='COLUMNA' THEN COLUMNA
 WHEN DESCP='COLUMNB' THEN COLUMNB 
 WHEN DESCP='COLUMNC' THEN COLUMNC ELSE NULL END AMT,
 B.ACNT
 FROM  
 TABLEA X
 JOIN
 TABLEB Y
 ON  X.TYPES=Y.TYPES
```

These are just sample data and there are around 10 types and more than 10 columns. Is there any other option apart from writing case statements for including all the columns to achieve this? Thanks

Comment: The `case` statement is probably the best way to go.

Comment: Case expression, not statement...

Answer (score 0):

Use [Teradata TD_UNPIVOT](http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_14_10/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035_1145_112A/Table_Operators.098.21.html) it's purpose is exactly what you need.